# How does the move constructor look like if I have a vector (or anything like it) member variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

The title pretty much sums up my question. In more detail: I know that when I declare a move constructor and a move assignment operator in C++11 I have to "make the other objects variables zero". But how does that work, when my variable is not an `array` or a simple `int` or `double` value, but its a more "complex" type?

In this example I have a `Shoplist` class with a `vector` member variable. Do I have to invoke the destructor of the `vector` class in the move assignment operator and constructor? Or what?

```
class Shoplist {
public:
    Shoplist() :slist(0) {};
    Shoplist(const Shoplist& other) :slist(other.slist) {};
    Shoplist(Shoplist&& other) :slist(0) {
        slist = other.slist;
        other.slist.~vector();
    }

    Shoplist& operator=(const Shoplist& other);
    Shoplist& operator=(Shoplist&& other);



    ~Shoplist() {};
private:
    vector<Item> slist;
};

Shoplist& Shoplist::operator=(const Shoplist& other)
{
    slist = other.slist;
    return *this;
}

Shoplist& Shoplist::operator=(Shoplist&& other)
{
    slist = other.slist;
    other.slist.~vector();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Look up the "rule of 0". The move constructor here is drastically wrong (you should never--or very nearly never--explicitly invoke a destructor!), but you can get a correct auto-generated one for free.

Comment: Also, you don't *have* to "make the other object variables zero", you could just leave it as it is (although that might not always be desirable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever a `std::vector` needs to do in order to move correctly, will be handled by its own [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

So, assuming you *want* to move the member, just use that directly:

```
Shoplist(Shoplist&& other)
  : slist(std::move(other.slist))
{}
```

and

```
Shoplist& Shoplist::operator=(Shoplist&& other)
{
    slist = std::move(other.slist);
    return *this;
}
```

In this case, you could as AndyG points out, just use `= default` to have the compiler generate exactly the same move ctor and move assignment operator for you.

Note that explicitly destroying the original as you did is definitely absolutely wrong. The `other` member will be destroyed *again* when `other` goes out of scope.

---

Edit: I did say *assuming you want to move the member*, because in some cases you might not.

Generally you want to move data members like this if they're logically part of the class, and much cheaper to move than copy. While `std::vector` is definitely cheaper to move than to copy, if it holds some transient cache or temporary value that isn't logically part of the object's identity or value, you might reasonably choose to discard it.

Comment: Though in your first block of code, `other` isn't it already `&&` rvalue as defined in the signature? So `std::move` makes any difference?

Comment: @Vassilis, `other` is in fact an lvalue within the scope of the move constructor. Check here for a nice explanation: https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html "... in our constructor, the object has a name; it will be alive for the entire duration of our function. ..."

Comment: @Hari, yes indeed, to summarize: All function parameters are `lvalue`s. Just their *type* can be `rvalue` references. Parameter types are used to distinguish function overloads.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing copy/move/destructor operations doesn't make sense unless your class is **managing** a resource. By managing a resource I mean be directly responsible for it's lifetime: explicit creation and destruction. The rule of 0 and The rule of 3/5 stem from this simple ideea.

You might say that your class is managing the `slist`, but that would be wrong in this context: the `std::vector` class is directly (and correctly) managing the resources associated with it. If you let our class have implicit cpy/mv ctos/assignment and dtors, they will correctly invoke the corresponding `std::vector` operations. So you absolutely don't need to explicitly define them. In your case the rule of 0 applies.

---

> I know that when I declare a move constructor and a move assignment
>   operator in C++11 I have to "make the other objects variables zero"

Well no, not really. The ideea is that when you move from an object (read: move it's resource from an object) then you have to make sure that your object it's left aware that the resource it had is no more under it's ownership (so that, for instance, it doesn't try to release it in it's destructor). In the case of `std::vector`, it's move ctor would set the pointer it has to the internal buffer to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that when I declare a move constructor and a move assignment operator in C++11 I have to "make the other objects variables zero"

This is not quite correct. What you must do, is maintain validity of the moved from object. This means that you must satisfy the class invariant.

If you have specified a special invariant for a particular class, that requires you to set member variables to zero, then perhaps such class might have to do so. But this is not a requirement for move in general.

---

> Do I have to invoke the destructor of the vector class in the move assignment operator and constructor?

Definitely not. The destructors of the members will be called when the moved from object is destroyed.

What you would typically do, is move construct/assign each member in the move constructor/assignment operator of the containing object. This is what the implicitly generated special member functions do. Of course, this might not satisfy the class invariant for all classes, and if it doesn't, then you may need to write your own versions of them.

---

The compiler will implicitly generate the special member functions for you, if you don't try to declare them yourself. Here is a minimal, but correct version of your class:

```
class Shoplist {
    vector<Item> slist;
};
```

This class is default constructible, movable and copyable.

Answer (score 0):

[The move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) should move member-wise:

```
Shoplist(Shoplist&& other)
    : slist(std::move(other.slist)) 
{}
```

Note, that the compiler generates move constructors for you (when possible) by member-wise move, as you would do by hand above.

Answer (score 0):

Move constructors are *allowed* (but *not* required) "steal" the contents of the moved-from object. This does *not* mean that they must "make the other objects variables zero". Moving a primitive type, for instance, is equivalent to copying it. What it does mean is that a move constructor can *transfer ownership* of data in the heap or free store. In this case, the moved-from object must be modified so that when it is destroyed (which should *not* happen in the move-constructor), the data it previously owned (before it was transferred) will not be freed.

Vector provides its own move constructor. So all you need to do in order to write a correct move constructor for an object containing a vector is to ensure the correct vector constructor is invoked. This is done by explicitly passing an r-value reference to the sub-object constructor, using `std::move`:

```
Shoplist(Shoplist&& other) :slist(std::move(other.slist)) {
   //... Constructor body
```

... But in fact you probably don't need to do this in general. Your copy and move constructors will be correctly auto-generated if you don't declare them **and** don't declare a destructor. (Following this practice is called the "rule of 0".)

Alternatively, you can force the compiler to auto-generate the move constructor:

```
Shoplist(Shoplist&& other) = default;
```